# Cannot see data fields in views on SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data reader's access on ssms.
I can see the tables but i cannot see any tables in views that created.
Thanks

Comment: tables in views? Could you try to explain further? if you mean you can't see the definition of the views, then no you won't be able to. You the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DBA perhaps has to execute one of those statements to give you access to DDL definitions of objects. Currently, you are limited to read data

```
USE [dbname]

-- via fixed database role
ALTER ROLE [db_ddladmin] ADD MEMBER [yourUser]

-- view ANY definition, as Larnu mentioned
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [yourUser]

-- limited scope to some certain schema, but can also object level
GRANT VIEW  DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[Backup] TO [yourUser]
```

**Update**

Objects  could be not visible in SSMS because such DENY granted:

```
DENY VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO User1
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for replying Alexander

Comment: I have a grant on select but views are empty

Comment: @DivyyGada, perhaps it was intentionally, I updated my answer

Comment: so perhaps I will have to check it with the dba